# Nonexistence of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics

Following is a doubt I got when I was reading Csiszar's Annals of Statistics paper "Why least squares and maximum entropy: An axiomatic approach to inference for linear inverse problems". 
He comes up with a set of axioms to justify $\ell_2$-norm minimisation in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

He also argues that $\ell_2$-norm minimization would not be appropriate if the space we consider consists of vectors with positive components,say, $\mathbb{R}_+^n$. Further he says that there exists sets of the form

$$L=\{v \in \mathbb{R}_+^n :Av=b\}$$

where $A$ is some $k\times n$ matrix and $u\notin L$ such that $\min_{v\in L}\|v-u\|_2$ is not attained in $L$.

I can't think of such an example.

Can someone think of such an example?

Comment: This has nothing to do with algebraic geometry.

Comment: sorry, I have removed that tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI Ashok,
  I think $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ requires strictly positive components. Then it's easy to come up with the situation above, namely consider $L$ to be the part of the line $x+y = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}_+^2$. And $u = (2,1)$. Then there is no closest point in $L$ to $u$, because it wants to be $(1,0)$, which has nonpositive component. So I guess $n=2$ and $A = (1,1)$ is a $1\times 2$ matrix, and $b=2$.

Comment: Thanks John Jiang. I didn't think that I would get such an easy example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(1 -1)$ and $b=(0)$. Then $L=\left\{{a\choose a}\vert a\in \mathbb R_+\right\}$, so for instance for $u={\ \ 1\choose -1}$ $\min_{v\in L}\|v-u\|_2=\sqrt{2}$ is not attained in $L$.

The point of the example is that the projection of $u$ to the linear space genrated by $L$ is is on the closure of $L$ but not in $L$. In other words, the problem is that $L$ is not closed.

Comment: Haha, looks like you are in less need for a point booster.

Comment: @John Jiang: ??

Comment: I too tried for the same $L$. Though $u\notin L$ I wanted the vector $u$ to be in the space we consider namely $\mathbb{R}_+^n$. So this doesn't serve as an example. Thanks any way!

Comment: I think what John Jiang means is: "Sándor already has high reputation score, and does not need to enhance his rep further by answering such simple questions." However, I think that was probably (i hope) meant in an light-hearted sense ;-)

Comment: @Ashok: Sándor mentions the key term: "not closed"

Comment: Yes Suvrit, but the point is that the $u$ in Sándor Kovács's example lies outside my space of interest $\mathbb{R}_+^n$.
I am wondering whether one can still find an example even if we relax the strictly positiveness to non negativeness.

Comment: would it be better to start a new post for the further question?

Comment: @Ashok: It was not clear from your question that this is what you're after. The positive part is **not** a space. The idea works the same way, just change $b$ to say $2$. That changes $L$ to the set of elements in the form $(a+2,a)$ with $a>0$ and $u=(1,1)$ works (taking $-u$ and shifting both $L$ and $u$ by $(2,0)$. I wrote down the principle that matters. Apparently you did not get that part. Cheers!

Comment: @Suvrit: I thought the idea was to answer questions, not enhancing our reputations. :)

Comment: @Sandor and Suvrit: Light-hearted indeed. I have never gotten a single correct answer before so would like to see how many points it's worth:)

Comment: @Sándor: Indeed. I feel ashamed.

Comment: Dear Ashok, there is no reason to be ashamed, the point of this website (I think) is to help each other's understanding of mathematics. We all commit mistakes (I definitely do that a lot!) and overlook things. No harm in that. Take care! 

Comment: Let me add, that unfortunately it is really hard to convey one's mood in a comment and one often reads something into what someone else wrote that the other person did not mean. An innocent comment may seem offensive for another person and can lead to bad feelings. I definitely did not mean to do that to you! :)

Comment: @John Jiang: I took it lightheartedly and thought it was OK. At the same time I wanted to make the point that my goal in posting an answer is not motivated by enhancing my reputation. Then again, I totally understand your point and find nothing wrong with it. And I agree that I can easily say that I don't care about enhancing my reputation when it is already enhanced. Cheers!